# creating new logic app templates

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Can we create new templates for logic apps and make it availble for certain groups to extend/customize their logic on top of it?

Scenario: I have many integrations to be done. All integrations will have a sequence of actions 1->2->3->4…10. Depending on some requirements, only the action 10 will vary in each logic app. In some cases, the 10th action could be writing to a topic, in others, it may be writing the data to an event hub.

My ask is, can I create a template for such logic apps for my team? So that when creating a new logic app using that template, it already comes with actions 1..9 and the developer’s work is reduced?

Comment: What you have done and any error message you have got? I think you could use `condition` after 9 action like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pD16l.png) and add the topic or event hub you want in different branch.

Comment: To confirm, 1-9 will be the same process in all cases.  Only 10 will vary.

Answer (score 0):

According to the product roadmap, (https://trello.com/b/9GhzIReR/azure-logic-apps-product-roadmap) there will be reusable modules. But I'm not sure whether these will be within the subscription (private) or for all users.

What you can do is to create a "template" Logic App and ask your devs to **clone** from it on the portal and just add the last action. Cloning a workflow is quite straight forward, you just need to specify a resource group and the new name.

Another option is to create an ARM template that contains the 9 steps, and then deploy as required. You could find some handy tips to create ARM templates for Logic Apps [here](https://platform.deloitte.com.au/articles/preparing-azure-logic-apps-for-cicd)

HTH

Comment: The last link is broken